# Unselect all layers and clear the legend in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping

Is the there a way of clearing the legend in Openlayers by unselecting all the layers? We have a map that starts with several layers.

I was thinking that we might be able to add a button to the map that would do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "legend". AFAIK OpenLayers have no legend-control. Are you using some kind of framework such as GeoEXT or mapfish?

Answer (score 1):

You could use some JavaScript like the following:

```
 for(var i=0;i<map.layers.length;i++) {
    if (!map.layers[i].isBaseLayer)
      map.layers[i].setVisibility(false)
 }
```

This will disable all layers except base layers. The legend ([LayerSwitcher](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/LayerSwitcher-js.html)) will be updated automatically.

Comment: unicoletti - thanks for that I'll give it a whirl. By legend I did mean LayerSwitcher